# how to display values from has_one association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to Show Data in view.

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :bank_account
end

class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :employee
end

Comment: "I want to Show Data in view" What stops you from doing it? What's the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To show data on view, you first need to get the instance data from the db:

```
@employee = Employee.last //gives you data for the last employee
```

Since you need to show it in the view you will be needing an instance variable so that the same can be accessed in the view.

Now, in the view, access the specific data using:

```
@employee.name  # employee specific data

@employee.bank_account.value # access associated record
```

Hope it answers the question.